# In C, what is a safe alternative to sscanf?

Tags: c

I found online that in C++ there's an alternative, but what about plain-old C? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: Unlike a few standard functions in C, `sscanf` can be used safely. As doing pretty much anything in C requires care you might need to be more specific about your particular use case to get "safer" solutions to whatever problem you are considering.

Comment: Hmm, so sscanf is safer than ... ?

Comment: Safe in what respect? Do you have a particular use-case with which you are concerned?

Comment: Well just security-wise, safer against hackers I guess. Maybe it's safe enough then . BTW This is part of an assignment, and I googled to no avail so I said lemma try SO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with it.

Since you have the string in memory, you can safely avoid buffer overflows by being careful about the arguments you pass.  For example, if you're scanning into a string, using `"%s"`, just use a target buffer big enough to hold the biggest string that could possibly be there (and make sure that the source buffer is a valid string, i.e., that it's `'\0'`-terminated).

One danger of all the `*scanf()` functions is that if you're scanning a numeric value, and the input value is too big to be represented in the target type, the behavior is undefined.  For example, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    const char *s = "999999999999999999999999999";
    int n;
    sscanf(s, "%d", &n);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

has undefined behavior (unless `INT_MAX` is really really big).

You can safely scan numeric values using the `strto*()` functions: `strtol()`, `strtoll()`, `strtoul()`, `strtoull()`, `strtof()`, `strtod()`, `strtold()`.  Their behavior on errors is a bit tricky, but at least it's well defined.

Comment: Good answer. I'll add that instead of `%s` which can overrun your buffer, I'd strongly recommend always explicitly setting the buffer size: `char buf[50]; sscanf(unknownString, "%49s", buf);` This truncates (and null-terminates) too-long strings, but protects memory.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're looking for the "m" modifier.  It dynamically allocates memory to hold the extracted string, so as to avoid buffer overflows.  The only drawback is that it's a GNU extension, so e.g. MSVC probably won't recognize it.

Here is an [existing Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926883/scanf-dynamic-allocation) on that topic.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str;
    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    scanf("%ms", &str);

    printf("Hello %s!\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the OP is asking about plain-old-C, so probably not an extension like that. There's also `%as` in POSIX

Comment: I believe `char *str = NULL` is better. Otherwise, extremely painful to handle various error conditions (EOF, IO Error, parsing errors).

Comment: @dash-o: Better yet to check scanf()'s return value.

Answer (score 4):

Under Windows, you can use `sscanf_s` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx) which require you to provide the buffer length for every `%s` match as an argument right after the buffer argument.

For example, `sscanf_s( tokenstring, "%s", s, (unsigned)_countof(s) );`.