# scanf dynamic allocation

Tags: c, string, dynamic, input

For whatever reason the following code prints (null):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *foo; 
    scanf("%ms", &foo);
    printf("%s", foo);
    free(foo);
}
```

I'm trying to allocate memory for a string dynamically but as I said earlier my program simply outputs (null). I worked around this by making a function using getche and realloc but it seems almost pointless due to the fact that I also had to program what would happen if the user entered backspace, tab, etc.. But as I said that is just a work around and I would rather know why the above code is not working...

Additional Information:

I am using the Pelles C IDE v7.00  and compiling with the C11 standard

Comment: What is `%ms` intended to do?

Comment: @Greg The m flag should dynamically allocate memory to contain the input.

Comment: Is that nonstandard? I don't see that in my `scanf` documentation.

Comment: I don't see anything about `m` flag in my copy of C11 (which is, admittedly, a draft). Where did you get it? It looks to me as something chiefly GCC specific, which you are unlikely won't find in any other library implementation.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-09/msg01342.html Maybe my compiler doesn't support it? and in C99 there was the `a` flag I thought the `m` flag was the new version of this according to this document

Comment: That's a shame, such a great little flag but I can't use it.

Comment: The `m` flag is in POSIX now, added in the 2008 edition. The good thing about standards...

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what that means for me, what would I have to do to utilize the `m` flag?

Comment: Your `foo` already is a pointer, so you should not use `&foo` (address of `foo`) when passing it to `scanf`. `scanf("%ms", foo);` is correct.

Comment: @Palec `scanf("%ms", &foo);` is correct. The `%ms` specifier allocates memory and "returns" a pointer to that memory. The initial value of `foo` is unused.

Comment: You’re right, @MattMcNabb. Thanks for disabusing me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not seeing `%m` in section 7.21.6.2 of the [Draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the section on `fscanf`).  I suggest that you avoid it and call `malloc()` as you would in C99.

Comment: Seeing as you can't predict how much space to allocate with `scanf("%s")`, I'd also recommend avoiding `scanf` entirely and using `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Comment: The `%ms` notation is a POSIX extension in [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) compared with the standard C version of `scanf()`.

Comment: Maybe use this in conjunction with a method that tells you how big the data is, that you receive in advance (on the stack). Just an idea.

Answer (score 2):

%m is a POSIX extension, which may be why it's not available in Pelles C.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the man page for scanf/sscanf (page 3, from line 270-290) that states the following:

> EXAMPLE
>
> To  use the dynamic allocation conversion specifier, specify m as a length modifier (thus %ms or %m[range]).  The caller must free(3) the returned string,  as  in  the following example:
>
> ```c
> char *p;
> int n;
>
> errno = 0;
> n = scanf("%m[a-z]", &p);
> if (n == 1) {
>    printf("read: %s\n", p);
>    free(p);
> } else if (errno != 0) {
>    perror("scanf");
> } else {
>    fprintf(stderr, "No matching characters\n");
> }
> ```
>
> As  shown in the above example, it is necessary to call free(3) only if the scanf() call successfully read a string.

Source: SCANF(3) - Linux Programmer's Manual - GNU - 2013-01-30

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux 3.2.0 amd 64 with **gcc 4.7.2**. Using the code:

```
char *s; 
scanf("%ms", &s);
printf("%s", s);
free(s);
```

works fine but it won't accept whitespaces.

For static allocation, you can instead use:

```
char s[100];
printf("Enter string (max 99 characters): ");
scanf("%100[^\n]s", &s);
printf("You entered: %s\n", s);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry for that but you are not helping him because if you take a look at your `scanf()` function you will definitely realize that it is wrong ! it should be `scanf("%ms", s)` as s is a pointer in itself ! Please note that there is no `&` before the `s`. Besides keep in mind that it  will not work for the next `scanf` in the program if there are any !!! Hope it is clear !!!

Comment: @Meninx: no, with `%ms`, it should be `scanf("%ms", &s)`. The POSIX `m` extension allocates the string for you and assigns it to `s`, which must be of type `char*`.

Comment: The `scanf("%ms", &s)` is correct, the call modifies the pointer stored in `s`. However, **the `scanf("%100[^\n]s", &s)` is wrong**. It needs to be `scanf("%99[^\n]", s)`. In this case, the pointer to the first byte of the buffer needs to be passed by value, so `s` is correct. And the `s` after the closing bracket `]` is wrong, it's not part of the conversion. But, most importantly, the buffer must be longer than the field width to leave room for the terminating null byte. **Using a field width of 100 for a 100 byte buffer allows users to overrun the buffer**.

Answer (score 0):

as [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3616293/arun) says, this solution is right and [Meninx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4392605/meninx)'s opinion is wrong:

```
char *s;
scanf("%ms", &s);
printf("%s", s);
free(s);
```

I have read the 'man scanf', it says:

An optional 'm' character. This is used with string conversions(%s, %c, %[),
and relieves the caller of the need to allocate a corresponding buffer to 
hold the input: instead, scanf() allocates a buffer of sufficient size, and 
assigns the address of this buffer to the corresponding **pointer** 
argument, which should be **a pointer to a char * variable** (this variable 
does not need to be initialized before the call). The caller should
subsequently free(3) this buffer when it is no longer required.