# Sscanf not behaving as intended in extracting strings

Tags: c, scanf

I have a SPARQL query like "select ?Y ?Z where ...". All that I want to do is extract the variables "?Y" and "?Z". I wrote the following loop:

```
char *p = "select ?Y ?Z where condition";
char *array[2];

p += strlen("select");        /* advancing the pointer */

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
        sscanf(p, "%m[?a-zA-Z] %[^\n]", array[i], p);    /* 'm' tells sscanf to perform dynamic memory allocation */
        printf("%s, ", array[i]);
        printf("%s, ", p);
}
```

However, I am not getting the intended behavior. array[1] contains garbage and array[2] contains null.

Comment: it might be related to the open /*

Comment: what do you mean by open?

Comment: check after you advance the pointer where it is please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.  Two are correctly diagnosed by [zubergu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581593/zubergu) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896538/15168): (1) passing a `char *` where a `char **` is needed (see [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)), and (2) trying to overwrite the string you are scanning which is readonly in the first place and in any case invokes undefined behaviour.

Another is that you do not check the return status from `sscanf()`.  You probably need to something like this:

```
char *p = "select ?Y ?Z where condition";
char *array[2];

p += strlen("select");

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int offset;
    if (sscanf(p, " %m[?a-zA-Z]%n", &array[i], &offset) != 1)
        ...report error and break loop...
    printf("%s, ", array[i]);
    p += offset;
}
```

Notice the blank before the conversion specification to skip leading spaces.

If you have a version of `sscanf()` that supports the notation, this code should work correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p = "select ?Y ?Z where condition";
    char *array[2] = { 0, 0 };
    int i;
    int j;

    p += strlen("select");

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int offset;
        printf("p = <<%s>>\n", p);
        if (sscanf(p, " %m[?a-zA-Z]%n", &array[i], &offset) != 1)
            break;
        printf("%d: <<%s>> (offset = %d)\n", i, array[i], offset);
        p += offset;
    }
    printf("%d: all done\n", i);

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        free(array[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Mac OS X 10.9 does not support the `m` modifier; neither do older versions of Linux (note to self: must update available VMs).  When tested on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative, I got the output:

```
p = << ?Y ?Z where condition>>
0: <<?Y>> (offset = 3)
p = << ?Z where condition>>
1: <<?Z>> (offset = 3)
2: all done
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great help..I presume that the format specifier %n gets populated with the number of bytes read.

Comment: Yes; the `%n` reports the number of bytes read at the point where the conversion specification is processed.  It does not count as one of the conversions, though, for the return value (it always succeeds).

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html 
where in example there is

```
char *p;
n = scanf("%m[a-z]", &p);
```

I assume that you should change your

```
sscanf(p, "%m[?a-zA-Z] %[^\n]", array[i], p);
```

to

```
sscanf(p, "%m[?a-zA-Z] %[^\n]", &array[i], p);
```

Look how `%m` is paired with `char **` not with `char*`.

I suggest reading [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926883/scanf-dynamic-allocation) discussion, too.

I also noticed that your `p` is `char *` and you initialize it with string constant, then try to overwrite it with call to sscanf.

Besides that, you read from and write to memory `p` points to in the same function call. I'm not 100% sure here, but that's probably undefined behaviour right there.

Hope it helps.