# What's wrong with my decoder? Why does it freeze after prompting the user?

Tags: c, debugging, prompt, freeze

The goal is to prompt the user to either encode an input file and write the code to an output file or decode an input file and write the message to an output file. Whenever I run the program, although it compiles, it stops responding as soon as the prompt character is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int encode(FILE * fp1, FILE * fp2);
int decode(FILE * fp1, FILE * fp2);
int main() {
       char prompt;
       printf("Would you like to encode a message into a file?\n");
       printf("Or would you like to decode a message from a file?\n");
       printf("Enter e to encode or d to decode.\n");
       scanf("%c", prompt);
       FILE *fp1, *fp2;
       char filename1[INT_MAX], filename2[INT_MAX];
       printf("Enter input file: ");
       scanf("%s", filename1);
       fp1 = fopen(filename1, "r");
       printf("Enter output file: ");
       scanf("%s", filename2);
       fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w");
       if (fp1 == NULL) {
               printf("The file does not exist.\n");
               return 0;
       }
       if (fp2 == NULL) {
               printf("The file oes not exist.\n");
               return 0;
       }
       switch (prompt) {
              case 'e':
                   encode(fp1, fp2);
                   break;
              case 'E':
                   encode(fp1, fp2);
                   break;
              case 'd':
                   decode(fp1, fp2);
                   break;
              case 'D':
                   decode(fp1, fp2);
                   break;
              default:
                      break;
       }
       return 0;
    }

int encode(FILE * fp1, FILE * fp2) {
     char ci, co;
     while (fscanf(fp1, "%c", ci) != EOF) {
           for (ci = 97; ci <= 122; ci++)
               co = ci - 64;
           for (ci = 48; ci <= 57; ci++)
               co = ci + 11;
           switch (ci) {
                case 32:
                     co = 69;
                     break;
                case 10:
                     co = 70;
                     break;
                case 13:
                     co = 71;
                     break;
                default:
                     break;
           }
           fprintf(fp2, "%c", co);
     } 
     printf("Your message has been encoded.\n");
     system("pause");
     return 0;
} 

int decode(FILE * fp1, FILE * fp2) {
     char ci, co;
     while (fscanf(fp1, "%c", ci) != EOF) {
           for (ci = 33; ci <= 58; ci++)
               co = ci + 64;
           for (ci = 59; ci <= 68; ci++)
               co = ci - 11;
           switch(ci) {
                case 69:
                     co = 32;
                     break;
                case 70:
                     co = 10;
                     break;
                case 71:
                     co = 13;
                     break;
                default:
                     break;
           }
           fprintf(fp2, "%c", co);
     } 
     printf("Your message has been decoded.\n");
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously trying to allocate an array of `INT_MAX` bytes *on the stack*?

Comment: `char filename1[INT_MAX]` --> `char filename1[FILENAME_MAX]`

Comment: As a followup to to @EOF, I would be surprised if that even ran.  There are better ways to make things safe from buffer overruns than blowing up the stack yourself with those arrays,

Answer (score 4):

There may be other problems but the first one is here:

```
scanf("%c", prompt);
```

should be

```
scanf("%c", &prompt);
```

See full function definition and example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Also,

```
char filename1[INT_MAX], filename2[INT_MAX];
```

There's no way that this is a good idea.  Either allocate dynamically or at least use a more reasonable number for a filename.  256 should be plenty for a filename.  If you're really worried about a buffer overflow in your homework assignment, you can use a technique mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16043903/951784) to properly allocate memory for an input string (as long as you're using a GNU compiler):

```
char *str;
printf("Enter your filename:\n");
scanf("%ms", &str);

printf("Hello %s!\n", str);
free(str);
```

The %m will automatically allocate a string of proper size, avoiding buffer overflows.

This one is just for readability:

```
    switch (prompt) {
    case 'e':
        encode(fp1, fp2);
        break;
    case 'E':
        encode(fp1, fp2);
        break;
    case 'd':
        decode(fp1, fp2);
        break;
    case 'D':
        decode(fp1, fp2);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Can be condensed down to:

```
switch (prompt) {
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
        encode(fp1, fp2);
        break;
    case 'd':
    case 'D':
        decode(fp1, fp2);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: 256 as a max leaves room for buffer overflows.  This may be a different issue to address later though, depending on if this is homework or not.

Comment: I've added a safe allocation method to address this.  Thanks.

Comment: Note: Initializing `char *str = NULL;` useful to cope with `scanf("%ms", &str); free(str);` that failed to scan anything.

Answer (score 1):

**First**:

`scanf` should have a **reference** to a `char` address for its second parameter. You are passing its **value** instead. rost0031 mentions that on his answer.

**Second**:

you'll very likely receive a **Stack Overflow** from instantiating big arrays of `char` on the stack. So do like this instead:

```
char* filename1 = malloc(INT_MAX);
char *filename2 = malloc(INT_MAX);
```

In case you don't know what a `malloc` does, it basically **dynamically allocates** memory on the **Heap** (which is much more resourceful than the **Stack**).
These kind of allocation require that you `free` the memory after you are finished using them (otherwise you'll get **memory leaks**):

```
free(filename1);
free(filename2);
```

**Third**:

Your `decode` and `encode` functions do not need to return `int`, since you are not returning anything useful and your calls do not expect a result. You can make them `void` and remove the `return 0;` before the end of the scope:

```
void decode(FILE * fp1, FILE * fp2);
void encode(FILE * fp1, FILE * fp2);
```

Comment: It is more likely that the OP does NOT need to allocate `2147483647` characters. Second -- **do NOT cast the return of `malloc`**.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well. Casting the `malloc` allows for better compatibility with `C++`. If you are using pure C and not a **C++ compiler** then I completely agree with you. I'll edit the answer, nevertheless. But I warn the OP that the `malloc` won't work on **C++ compilers** (at least not **MSDN**) without a cast.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino: casting malloc in C may result in the compiler hiding a warning which could cause crashes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/951784

Comment: Agreed, but the OP should be also warned that:
"True. However, in C++ the cast is required, so if you want your code to work in both, you'll have to compromise. But in pure C, don't do the cast for the reasons you stated. –  jalf Mar 3 '09 at 10:36"

Comment: The point being -- do you see a `C++` tag attached to the question? I understand what you are saying about `C++`, but it doesn't belong in answer to a `C` tagged question.  You edit is fine, but may still be a bit bewildering to others.

Comment: I do that mostly because new programmers will most likely use popular compilers (which are all C++) and won't get why the code does not compile. But, if you guys think that my edit do not attend the community constraints for tags, there we go with another edit.